# cant stop url default event

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the function that i am using:

```
$('.urlz').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    log('Url of link : ' + url.toString());
    if (url.indexOf("bridge.asp") < 0) {
        var site_domain = fnGetDomain(url);
        //  window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is the element..

```
<a href="bridge.asp?sitename=webcing" target="_blank" class="urlz">Visit The Site</a>
```

could it be that something fires before my funciton, i have already that function in document.ready..

Comment: preventDefault **and** return false should not be necessary. Here is a good article concerning the (mis)use of return false: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return false` is in the wrong location... it's currently within the `if` statement... move it to the end...

```
$('.urlz').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var url=this.href;
  log('Url of link : '+url.toString());
  if(url.indexOf("bridge.asp")<0){
    var site_domain=fnGetDomain(url);
    //  window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
  }
  return false;   
});
```

Comment: this should make no difference, since `.preventDefault()` is supressing the default action already.

Comment: Glad to help @DmitryMakovetskiyd - although I'm confused because  what Christoph is saying also makes sense - but if it works, then it works!

Comment: i put prevent default in the if condition too.. i think